# Finding obsolete/dated scripts from retired arcscripts.esri.com?

Tags: arcgis-platform, esri-company

How can I find scripts/tools/add-ins which are linked from any website and reference the retired http://arcscripts.esri.com/ site?

I first try looking them up in the new site, https://codesharing.arcgis.com but most of the time I cannot find what I am looking for in https://codesharing.arcgis.com and try to find cached (or archived or other links referenced) versions of the source to at least find the publisher, so I can do an in-depth web search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are echo-ing the thoughts of @StephenLead on GeoNet in a thread titled [Please restore ArcScripts](https://community.esri.com/thread/182094-please-restore-arcscripts):

> Anyone trying to visit http://arcscripts.esri.com is redirected to
>   ArcGIS Code Sharing - but the old content from ArcScripts has not been
>   ported across.
>
> I get that ArcScripts is no longer active, but this does not mean that
>   all of the content on ArcScripts is useless. There is many YEARS'
>   worth of user contributions on ArcScripts, which will be lost if this
>   resource is removed.
>
> Esri - can you please remove the redirect on
>   http://arcscripts.esri.com and just include a note telling people to
>   check ArcGIS Code Sharing for up-to-date code?

which was responded to by Jim Barry of Esri:

> Ok folks, here's something else long overdue. The link below is a
>   spreadsheet that contains a listing of the contents of the ArcScripts
>   database when it was frozen in 2010 and pulled offline in 2016. If you
>   see something in there you want, let me know (reply here, or direct
>   message, or email jbarry at esri), or anyone in Tech Support. We can
>   get it for you. The first column is the "Dbid" of the item which helps
>   us find the item by filename. Also important to know that items
>   between 13022-15629 are currently missing for reasons that might be
>   related to why we needed to pull it down in 2016, as are some others
>   in the list if they were deleted by the owner at some point after
>   uploading them.
>
> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26206155/share/ArcScripts_Items.xlsx

Unfortunately, as [commented by @whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267317/finding-obsolete-dated-scripts-from-retired-arcscripts-esri-com#comment424898_267350):

> Jim Barry's link goes to a "File Not Found" page

To address that I recommend contacting Jim via the above thread.